# Baffled by high-rep C vs. C++ axe-grinding. How should I react?

Tags: support

So recently I got a comment on one of my [old answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/376895/75166).

When I wrote the answer I didn't know too much about writing scopes in any programming language (I still don't). I did my research and posted my conclusions of my findings, with links and everything. Now this commenter comes by and says, that I am mistaken. That Canonical isn't trying to push C to program scopes as their premier language but C++.

I rechecked my sources and couldn't find any mention of C++. So I got back to the commenter and asked why he thinks it's C++ and not C. On this he made a general statement about what C and C++ is and isn't and changed my answer to support his view: that Canonical is push C++ programmed scopes.

Now, I'd just change my answer back to my version and flag the comments as off-topic. But since this a 10k+ user I wanted to double check how to react. Also I found it strange that all of a sudden his two comments had gotten up-votes.

I don't even care about C or C++, I want (my/the?) answer be as factually correct as possible.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it seems the *original* plan was to port scopes to C, but later the plan changed to C++ and the original answer didn't get updated. Fast forward to now and the API is all C++. Your answer came up around a scopes discussion in chat regarding the [scope development competition](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2014/10/scope-development-competition/). Since all of the API was written in C++ your answer was assumed to be off slightly, someone added a comment to this effect.

When they checked out your source a formatting confusion made it look like it said *C***, which was reasonably taken to mean a generalization, hence your answer was edited.

Because of this confusion I talked to David Planella in IRC and he has [updated the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/310670/44179) to reflect the current situation.

Unfortunately several misunderstandings made this look somewhat sketchy (factual wise), but those have all been cleared up so we should all be good :)

Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: I +1'ed this...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an axe to grind. I edited your answer because it wasn't accurate, and at the time you wrote it you didn't understand the difference. It crossed my screen for some reason, I honestly don't remember why. Probably related to the recent scopes competition (read as I didn't single you out for no reason).

So, I didn't edit David Planella's answer, which you referenced because he said the words C**. That indicates that he understands the difference and will make a future reader ask themselves what he meant. You did no such thing, so I did the edit.

*I put in chat for peer review, so you're welcome to come there for some debate if you're honestly concerned.*

See: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376633/why-cant-i-find-any-tutorial-for-unity-scope-and-python-for-ubuntu-13-10/376895#comment749395_376895)

Comment: Actually, the \*\* was just part of David's formatting (he was bolding text). I talked to him in IRC and he's updating it now though.

Comment: @hbdgaf I wish you would have responded with a link which supports your view as Seth did.

Comment: I wish your answer was accurate...  but oh well.

Comment: @hbdgaf Cool, sounds like it was all just a simple misunderstanding, things have changed and fonts are weird ;)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my sources weren't precise and that the high-rep commenter raised my axe-grinding flags for nothing :P

Comment: I talked to David Planella in IRC and he is taking a look :)